# Rails 4 Routing - undefined local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-routing

I have a payments table. In the index view I list all payments in a table and in the show view I'd like to show a form of all payments where a user can select which ones to further process.

Above the table in the index action view I have:

```
<%= link to "Customise", show_payment_path %>
```

Then in the controller:

```
  def show
    @payments = Payment.all
  end
```

In my routes file:

```
resources :payments
```

The error I am getting is:

```
undefined local variable or method `show_payment_path'
```

I have tried

```
<%= link_to 'Customise Sepa Mandate', show_payments_path %>
```

as well but that gives the same error. As does using url instead of path.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

for that make your own routes and create their own path variable such as

```
resources :payments, except: [:show]  do
  get '/show' => "payments#show", on: collection, as: :show
end
```

Comment: Can I then keep show_payments_path? Or does that change as well?

Comment: Also this is now giving me: local jump error no block given (yield)

Comment: you can't keep that variable find variable by run command rake routes in his terminal

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still very new to rails. It's probably obvious. I ran rake routes but it doesn't really help that I can see. What variable are you talking about?

Comment: In routes.rb I wrote your answer then in my view file: <%= show_payments_path %>

Comment: thats why i am telling you write your routes code here which you write in your file

Comment: also first you need to check which path variable create there then write it in view you can't write this <%= show_payments_path %>

Comment: I wrote down what you said in your answer. I copied and pasted it so it's exact.

Comment: I can't check because rake routes is now giving that error.

Comment: there is some routes syntax error so it raise an error.... may be you check the syntax....

Comment: you can correct it by this syntax which i wrote in my routes  file

Comment: resources :posts, except: [:index] do
      get "mypost/(:topics)"=>"posts#myposts", on: :collection, as: :myposts
      # instead of that use facebook like
      resources :comments
    end

Comment: if this not work then paste whole routes file code here... i will check that

Comment: Rake routes gives me:  show_payments GET    /payments/payments(/:show)(.:format)            payments#show but when I change show_payments_path to show_payments I get undefined local variable or method `show_payments'

Comment: keep that same show_payments_path, _path and _url are postfix of that variables which creates....

Answer (score 0):

The path for resourceful-routed `show` actions is just `payment_path` (singular resource) or `payment_path(id)`. Your “customize” link would lead me to believe you actually want `edit_payment_path(id)`, though.

See [Rails Guides — Generating Paths and URLs From Code](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code) for more info.

Comment: I don't actually want edit, I want to list all payments and index is already taken. payment_path gives me: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"payments"} missing required keys: [:id] (I have @payments = Payment.all in the controller action)

Comment: That's because, as I said, `payment_path` is for when you have a singular resource — your routes specify `resource: payment` and you don't have an index. If you need an index of payments you should use `resources :payments` then your path is `payments_path`, but that routes to the `index` action/method of `PaymentsController`. If it goes anywhere else you're doing it *wrong*. What is `index` if not an `index` of payments?

Answer (score 0):

Run rake routes command to see available routes and correct syntax.

Pass show_payment_path(:id) to get the particular payment show page.